# I can not display images with waigtail

Tags: python, django, image, wagtail

I'm trying to use insert images with wagtail cms but accuse the following error: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'get_rendition'

I have read the documentation but there they use a for to display several images but I want to show only one

models:

```
class HomePage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
    ]

class BlogPageGalleryImage(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(HomePage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='gallery_images')
    image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        related_name='+',
    )
    caption = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=250)

    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('image'),
        FieldPanel('caption'),
    ]
```

base.html:

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags %}
{% image page.gallery_images.all width-400 as my_image %}
```

I wanted to insert only one image dynamically, it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You can't do that. page.gallery_images.all is a queryset. You have to put that inside the for loop and loop through page.gallery_images.all with {% for i in page.gallery_images.all %} and then to render only one you can use {%if forloop.first %} render it. Or you can use slice filter as well.

Comment: Is it not possible if I change the models?

Comment: @DaviLuis You have one to many relationship there. You can always add an image field to your HomePage model if all you need is a single image.